# how to recover from duplicate key in mongoose + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I've created a signup form using mongoose and express 3

Its possible the user already exists with that username, in which case I get an err.code 11000 (duplicate key). How should I handle existing users?

This is what I'm doing now....but I'm not sure checking error code is best way:

```
  user.save(function(err){
    if ( err ) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(err.code);

      //duplicate key
      if ( err.code == 11000 ) {
        req.flash('error', 'User already exists');
        res.redirect('/signup');
        return;
      }
    }

    res.locals.user = user;
    req.session.user = user;
    //res.locals.session = req.session;
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Looks pretty clean.  What in particular doesn't feel quite right about it to you?

Comment: Just the fact that I let the db throw an error instead of maybe checking for a user first.

Comment: It depends on what would make another solution 'a better way' in your situation.  Not trying to be difficult, but if this is functionally correct and its performance is adequate and it's maintainable...?

Comment: i wouldn't want to fill up the error log with duplicate key errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried this yet, but this is what I'm thinking will avoid causing an error:

```
//look for existing user first
user.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
  if ( err ) throw err;

  //existing user found, stop registration
  if ( user ) {
      res.flash('error', "That user already exists");
      res.redirect('/signup');
      return;
  }

  //create new user
  var user = new User({ username: req.body.username });

  user.save(function(err){
   if ( err ) throw err;
      res.flash('info', "Your account has been created");
      res.redirect('/account');
  });
});
```

Comment: You can also use `.count()` which is slightly more succinct/memorable but doesn't allow for using the returned data if required.

Comment: Ps, I do think that mongoose should have something like `Model.saveUnique({username: req.body.username}, function (err) { ... });`

Comment: It is actually safer to handle the duplicate key error because it is possible for another request to have created the user between when `user.findOne()` reads the collection and `user.save()` executes. I.e., there’s a race condition where your API could throw a 5xx error. For a form where you’re expecting the user not to exist already, just trying to save it and then handling an anticipated DuplicateKey error is less code (no need for `user.findOne()`) and avoids this race condition. If you expect the entity to exist already, it might be more natural to try to load it first.

Comment: You'd use `user.findOneAndUpdate()` with `upsert` option if you do not want the error. It'll find existing or create one. To see if it was created or if it found existing, you need the `raw` answer. But if you just want to fail, the duplicate key error is fine.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
user.save(function(err){
  if ( err && err.code !== 11000 ) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.code);
    res.send('Another error showed up');
    return;
  }

  //duplicate key
  if ( err && err.code === 11000 ) {
    req.flash('error', 'User already exists');
    res.redirect('/signup');
    return;
  }

  res.locals.user = user;
  req.session.user = user;
  //res.locals.session = req.session;
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

You won't fill the error log this way.

Comment: isn't that what I had? What's hte difference. and errors do show up in log regardless...not sure how this is any different.

Comment: Sorry @chovy, modified my answer a bit.
- First conditional will happen in case the error is not a "duplicate key" error and return 'Another error showed up' to the client.
- Second conditional will happen in case the error is a "duplicate key" error.
- If no error, the script will go as instructed.

Comment: I see -- thanks. I still think errors are logged though, since the query threw an error. I might do user.findOne(.., function(err, user) { if ( !user ) new User(); user.save() });

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way of doing it to use logical approach

1. define auto-increment value as unique

**someModal.js**

```
var someschema = Schema({
    num: {type:Number,unique:true} // increment number 
});
var someModal = mongoose.model('someschema', someschema);
```

**controller.js**

```
async function insertDoc(someModal, lastNumFromDb, newDocToSave) {

    try {
        let lastNumFromDb = await someModal.findOne().sort({ _id: -1 }).lean();
        newDocToSave.lastNumFromDb = lastNumFromDb + 1
        let saved = await new someModal(newDocToSave).save();
        return saved;
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === '11000') {
            return insertDoc(someModal, lastNumFromDb, newDocToSave)
        }else{
            throw err
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are coming here in 2021 i wrote an [article](https://dev.to/ahmedmagdy11/handling-mongoose-dublication-errors-3f6n) about that.

you basically overwrite `create` or `insertOne` function and tackle the error before happening by doing indexscan.

Comment: It won't work when there is concurrency. The duplicate error means someone raced you to create the document. If both first search for the document, all but the first will still run into the duplicate error.

Comment: Solving Race condition is a thing and checking for duplication is another. i am saying there is a way to handle general duplication error, I don't know very much about solving a race condition since i didn't face this problem