# What does unique do in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm learning to build API's with node and mongoose. While creating my schema I set one of the values to be `unique : true`. But then again on the tutorial I am watching, the guy is checking again if the email exists in the database. Isn't this double work? If the value of email is set to be unique , why check with the findOne method if it exists? Shouldnt this `unique:true` take care of this?

Comment: Is the guide in the tutorial checking for `email` before insert?

Comment: yes @SagarChilukuri`

Comment: it seems double work but this way we can handle the error better, and display a user friendly error message in our app, while the uniqueIndex created with unique: true option will be also usefull if some documents must be added to the collection outside of the app.

Comment: @SuleymanSah aah , that makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost all cases you'll encounter, it doesn't make sense for the purpose of validation to query manually to check if the value is unique.
Mongoose automatically creates an unique index on the field and therefor mongodb is handling the actual validation in this case.

Even the case of error handling can easily be done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557473/how-to-recover-from-duplicate-key-in-mongoose-express). Still, depending on your code it could happen that there is some setup that will require a specific error handling of this case (e.g. if error handling is not done through with actual errors or the program-flow should not stop the process)

Another edge-case might be queries that circumvent the mongoose validation by using the mongodb driver directly, but as mentioned before, this shouldn't matter, as mongodb (not mongoose) will still throw an "duplicate key" error.

Finally using findOne to check for the existence of an object is not the most performant choice, as count or find().limit(1) might be more performant choices in this case.